# jQuery div text in second td

Tags: jquery, html-table

I want to get text in div inside second td in tr (firstName  in my example). Here is what I tried but it give me null.

I tried all below but no one is working.. here is complete code (this table is in popup):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#listings_row_landlord').dataTable();
});
```

and this code for alert:

```
var first_name  = $('#'+value).find("td:eq(1) div").html(); 

<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style=" border-radius:0px;" id="listings_row_landlord" class="display">
  <thead bgcolor="#E5E5E5" align="left" style="font-size:12px;" class="listing_headings">
  <tr><th width="20" style="text-align:center; width:20px;" class="sorting_desc" rowspan="1" colspan="1"></th><th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 94px;">First Name</th><th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 92px;">Last Name</th><th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 86px;">Mobile No</th><th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 83px;">Phone No</th><th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 50px;">Email</th><th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 95px;">Created By</th><th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 108px;">Assigned To</th><th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 59px;">Listed</th></tr></thead>


<tbody>
<?php
             while ( $rw = $oAppl->row($rs) ) {
             ?>


<tr id="<?php echo $rw["id"]; ?>" class="listing_rows odd"><td class=" sorting_1"><div id="item_action" style="text-align:center; width:22px;"><input type="radio" value="<?php echo $rw["id"]; ?>" id="checkbox_<?php echo $rw["id"]; ?>" name="select_landlord"></div></td>

<td>

<div style="width:100px;"><?php echo $rw["fname"]; ?> </div></td>

<td><div style="width:100px;"><?php echo $rw["lname"]; ?></div></td><td><div style="width:160px;"><?php echo $rw["mobile"]; ?></div></td><td><div style="width:150px;"><?php echo $rw["phone"]; ?></div></td><td><div style="width:180px;"><?php echo $rw["email"]; ?></div></td><td><div style="width:100px;">Admin Admin</div></td><td><div style="width:100px;">Admin Admin</div></td><td><div style="width:80px;"><?php echo $rw["created_date"]; ?></div></td></tr>
 <?php
               }
               ?>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: you're not closing your `<input>` tag

Comment: `$('td:last div', '#'+value).text();`

Comment: like that ^ short and sweet!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JdUqR/1/ is also working for me but dynamically not working

Answer (score 1):

Use [**eq()**](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) which is `zero-based` index so you need to use index 1 for second td instead of 2.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JdUqR/1/)**

```
var first_name  = $('#'+value).find("td:eq(1) div").html();
```

Comment: what is the value of *value* here: '#' + value <-- you sure that is being set?

Comment: yes this give me correct result..if i click on first,it alert me 1 and for second tr it is 2.....

Comment: my table id = listings_row_landlord,do we need to specify it,as i have alot of tables on page

Comment: i edit my post and provide my whole table html...can u pls check it again?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#listings_row_landlord #'+value).find("td:eq(1)").text();
```

Comment: Are you sure `value` is 1 ?

Comment: Whats your table `id/class` ?

Comment: table id=listings_row_landlord

Answer (score 0):

this is a little shorter, but adil & adeneo are very concise, imho.

```
var first_name  = $('#'+value).find("td:eq(1) > div").html();
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this , also check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ams4y/)

**HTML code**

```
  <table>
    <tr id="1" class="listing_rows odd">
       <td class=" sorting_1">
          <div id="item_action" style="text-align:center; width:22px;">
           <input type="radio" value="1" id="checkbox_1" name="select_landlord" />
          </div>
      </td>
      <td>
          <div style="width:100px;">firstName </div>
     </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**JS code**

```
  $(function(){
    alert($('#1 td:nth-child(2) div').html());
  })
```

CHECK this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CHke3/) with your code

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue.statically it was working well but dynamicall it was not...i just give dynamic id to div and get its html...which worked fine..thanks all for support